# Можно ли сказать "кончики губ"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Понятно, что правильно "уголки губ". Но в разговорной речи часто приходится слышать именно "кончики".

Answer (score 2):

По смыслу губа имеет два кончика, поэтому можно сказать **кончики губ**. Рот же имеет два уголка, поэтому можно сказать **уголки рта**. Две губы также имеют уголки губ.

Но реально эти понятия смешиваются, и мы получаем такую статистику (в Нацкорпусе):
**уголки губ ― 76, уголки рта ― 32, кончики губ ― 7, кончики рта ― 3.**

**Примеры:**

у Ольги округлились глаза, **кончики губ** приподнялись в улыбке. [Сергей Лукьяненко. Ночной дозор (1998)]. У него едва заметно дрожали опущенные **кончики губ.**.. [Юрий Трифонов. Утоление жажды (1959-1962)]

И снова улыбнулся ― так, что **кончики рта** поползли к ушам. [Марина Дяченко, Сергей Дяченко. Магам можно все (2001)]

Она почти не изменилась, только немного побледнела и чуть опустились **уголки губ.** [Ю. М. Нагибин. О Галиче ― что помнится (1994)]. С тех пор он стал замечать в ней все: каждый мягкий жест, опущенные **уголки губ**, карие громадные глаза. [Булат Окуджава. Упраздненный театр (1989-1993)]

Старость — это поражение, опущенные книзу **уголки рта**, это разочарование и сдача на милость победителя. [Ю. М. Нагибин. Один на один (1972-1979)]. Она радостно и лукаво улыбнулась, приподняв **уголки рта**. [А. Н. Толстой. Хождение по мукам/ Книга третья. Хмурое утро (1941)]. Наконецъ эпилогъ: темная башня, и надъ ней довольная луна ― **уголки рта** кверху. [В. В. Набоков. Приглашение на казнь (1935-1936)]

Answer (score 0):

Гугл-поиск упорно переделывает запрос с "кончиков" на "уголки", как Вы и хотели.

Но Гугл-Книги даёт множество примеров употребления именно "кончиков губ".

Вот цитата-картинка (текст не копируется) из [**Проспекта активного словаря русского языка**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=LUFqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA366&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijwKnh9vfPAhUjD5oKHQxXAXcQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1&f=false):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если поверить абзацу ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, может, и получатся у нас "кончики". )))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте текст вместо изображений! У многих пользователей, читающих ваши ответы может быть отключена загрузка изображений. Как результат, для них ваш ответ – это одно предложение.

Comment: Nicolas, я помню Вашу просьбу - потому и указала: текст не копируется! Но ссылка на то, что дано картинкой, - кликабельна.

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли сказать “кончики губ”?

.

Можно. См. примеры.

.

**Лев Толстой** *"Волк и ягнёнок"* (басня):

> Ягнёнок говорит: «Ах, волк, как я могу тебе воду мутить? Ведь я ниже
>   по воде стою, да и то **кончиками губ** пью». А волк говорит...

.

**Иван Бунин** *"Деревня"*:

> ― Ох, имей в виду: зачитаешься ― в кармане не досчитаешься! ― сказал,
>   тряхнув головой и дернув **кончиком губы**, Тихон Ильич.

.

**Андрей Белый** *"Серебряный голубь"*:

> Ну, подгуляли и губы: нижняя губа, скажем, отъехала от верхней ровно
>   на полвершка; и на самом **кончике губы** ― бородавка...

.

**Владимир Набоков** *"Истинная жизнь Севастьяна Найта"*:

> — А-а, хогрошее место, — сказал г. Зильберман, — очень хогрошее, — и
>   опустил **кончики губ** с выражением важного одобрения.